# RichText and RichTextParagraph documentation needed

Tags: rtf, ibm-doors

I'm writing a DXL script for exporting objects from DOORS to MS Word. 
But I have problem with copying of RTF tables. setRichClip function removes RTF tables when 'style' parameter is provided. I have an idea how to do it but I need DXL RichText and RichTextParagraph documentation. I didn't find it in DXL Reference Manual. Does any one have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the one I have Rich text is chapter 32. near the end of the manual
Assuming you are exporting from a column (view) in DOORS, you may find more success with:

richTextWithOle(column)

*Declaration*:
string richTextWithOle(Column c, Object o)

*Operation*:
Returns the text contained in column c for the object o as rich text, including OLE objects.

richTextWithOleNoCache(column)

*Declaration*:
string richTextWithOleNoCache(Column c, Object o)

*Operation*:
Returns the text contained in column c for the object o as rich text, including OLE objects, and clears the OLE cache.

If you are getting your contents directly from the attribute, the corresponding functions are:

richTextWithOle

*Declaration*:
string richTextWithOle(attrRef attr)

where attrRef is in one of the following formats:

(Object o).(string attrName)

(Module m).(string attrName)

(Link l).(string attrName)

and

richTextWithOleNoCache

richTextNoOle